# С чего начать верстать макет по образцу PSD?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Ничего до этого не верстал. Вот есть макет в PSD, с чего начинать-то? Надо бы разбить большую задачу на подзадачи, но тут просто в ступор вхожу, хоть и всю теорию знаю.

Comment: Нарежьте его для начала, как надо, и Save for Web -> html and images. Либо давайте более конкретный вопрос...

Comment: Как нарезать макет "как надо"?

Comment: @FrenchCheese Покажите, кстати, макет, ради интереса - попробую еще что-нибудь подсказать :)

Comment: вот два примера на которых я решил попрактиковаться

http://saveimg.ru/pictures/14-11-12/82ad697bfe7370eb83207215055731ab.jpg

http://blog.zaandr.ru/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/Free-Fictional-Design-Studio-Layout.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Возьмите [`HTML5 Boilerplate`](http://html5boilerplate.com/) или любой схожий по назначению `template`.
- В голове разбейте ваш макет на большие логические блоки.

> - Почитайте про [`Scaffolding.`](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html)
> - Подумайте, как грамотно вписать ваш контент в сетку с учетом того, что вы прочитали про `Scaffolding`.

- Аккуратно верстайте `div'ами` от большого к мелкому - если для какого-то блока у вас еще нет качественного контента, но вы знаете, как он примерно должен выглядеть, то заменяйте его прямоугольник соответствующего цвета и, когда будет время, прорабатывайте.

> [**Метод прогрессивного джипега,**](http://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/167/) короче.

Answer (score 2):

1. Разрезаем все картинки (режем полностью макет и отключаем текстовые блоки).
2. Далее от верха к низу верстаем блоки поочерёдно (пишем HTML и стилизуем его в соответствии с макетом).
3. Прикручиваем требуемые скрипты.
4. PROFIT.

Пробовал разбивать на подзадачи — сначала верстал сетку, потом натягивал фон на все элементы, потом текст, потом `CSS` и потом, потом, потом...
В общем, ничего не получалось. За несколько лет опыта остановился на варианте выше.